# $G\Sigma G'=\Sigma$ for all orthonormal matrices $G$

Tags: orthonormal, positive-definite, symmetric-matrices

This might look silly, but I am not being able to prove that

> If $G\Sigma G'=\Sigma$ for all orthonormal matrices $G$ and some fixed positive-definite symmetric matrix $\Sigma$, then $\Sigma$ must be of the form $\sigma^2 I$ where $I$ is the identty matrix. (All values are real).

I tried decomposing $\Sigma$ into eigen vectors but couldn't proceed. Can someone give me the click?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if $A$ (it's easier to type $A$ than $\Sigma$) is positiv symmetric, then 
$$A=O^T D O$$
for some diagonal matrix $D$ with positive entries and some orthogonal $O$. Multiplying from the left by $O$ and from the right by $O^T$ we get 
$$A = OA O^T = D$$

Now assume that two eigenvalues are different. Then choose an orthogonal transformation which exchanges the corresponding eigenvectors (and hence the eigenvalues in $D$) (resulting in a new matrix $D^*$). Then $D= D^*$ after applying the same calulation, a contradiction.

Comment: Aha.. Permutation matrices.. I get it.. Thanks